# Is it safe to use DB :: select and others in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

Queries are not always simple, and sometimes I need to create a pure SQL query, the query builder also does not fit. 
При использовании DB::select, подготовливаются ли 
переменные, которые подставлены в запрос?

Will there be a sql injection in this case?

```
$mastersInCity = DB::select('SELECT
        master_user.master_id,
        masters.specialization,
        category_letter_master.category_letter_id AS master_letter,
        COUNT(*) AS count_in_city

        FROM master_user

        LEFT JOIN masters ON master_user.master_id = masters.id
        LEFT JOIN category_letter_master ON category_letter_master.master_id = master_user.master_id 

        WHERE ' . $chooiseId . ' = ' . $cityId . ' GROUP 

        BY master_user.master_id, master_letter');
```

Or, in this case, it is better to use PDO directly, so as to manually prepare the request yourself, is it possible?

Comment: The use of an ORM such as Doctrine or Eloqent should combat the necessity to use DB::select in a lot of cases. Always a good idea to clean user inputted data though if this style of query is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mastersInCity = DB::select('SELECT
    master_user.master_id,
    masters.specialization,
    category_letter_master.category_letter_id AS master_letter,
    COUNT(*) AS count_in_city

    FROM master_user

    LEFT JOIN masters ON master_user.master_id = masters.id
    LEFT JOIN category_letter_master ON category_letter_master.master_id = master_user.master_id 

    WHERE ? = ? GROUP 

    BY master_user.master_id, master_letter', [$chooiseId, $cityId]);
```

This is equivalent to a prepared statement.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#running-queries

Edit: I am sure this can be done with eloquent simply, there is nothing too complex here. Something like:

```
MasterUser::with(['master', 'master_letter'])->withCount()->where($chooiseId, $cityId)->get()
```